# Unable to convert unicode into json in scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, screen-scraping, scrapy

```
import scrapy
import json
class GettingtonDSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "gettington_d"
    allowed_domains = ["gettington.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://api.gettington.com/v1/products?showMPP=false&rows=24&q=Keyword:south%20shore%20furniture&productfilter=null&callback=searchCallback']
    def parse(self, response):
    jsonresp = json.dumps(response.body)
    jsonresp= json.loads(jsonresp)
```

I have tried many methods but I failed:

- response.text
- encode('utf-8')
- response_body_as_unicode

None of above worked. How can the error be solved?

Comment: Are you encountering any error ? Any specific issue ? "None of the above worked." is not really helpful.

Comment: Yes, i have got [json object could not be decoded].

Comment: What is the output of print(response.body) ?

Comment: url product information with browser metadata like, searchCallback({metadata:{},products : {})

Comment: This is not json serializable.

Comment: any way to get that product information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to remove the unnecessary information first from the `response.body`, which isn't JSON serializable:

```
import re

    ...
    json_string = re.search(r'searchCallback\((.*)\)', response.body).group(1);
    jsonresp = json.loads(json_string)
```

Now you have a `dict` in `jsonresp`

Comment: You can also fetch `https://api.gettington.com/v1/products?showMPP=false&rows=24&q=Keyword:south%20shore%20furniture&productfilter=null&format=json` (ie. removing `&callback=searchCallback`, and asking for JSON format)